# asp.net ffind controlls with specific kind of ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code

```
<div id="campaignDiv" runat="server" style="display: block;">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="textDropdown">default</span><input runat="server" id="defaultdropdownID" value="default" type="checkbox"><label for="defaultdropdownID"></label></li>
        <li><span class="textDropdown">direct</span><input runat="server" id="directdropdownID" value="direct" type="checkbox"><label for="directdropdownID"></label></li>
        <li><span class="textDropdown">Sales</span><input runat="server" id="SalesdropdownID" value="Sales" type="checkbox"><label for="SalesdropdownID"></label></li>
        <li><span class="textDropdown">Support</span><input runat="server" id="SupportdropdownID" value="Support" type="checkbox"><label for="SupportdropdownID"></label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I want to get all the checkboxes in c#.

the checkboxes is exist in the div `id=campaignDiv` in the ul in the li

could u help please?

#### These checkboxes are added automatically

and all the IDs ends with "dropdownID"

could u help please?

Comment: it is wrong logically one unique id for every control in asp.net

Comment: Do you want to do this server side in `C#` code or client in `Javascript`?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad they end with "dropdownID" but not equal to it. for eaxmplae: "defaultdropdownID" and "serverdropdownID"

Comment: @DavidG server side, by c# code.